# Get full text search configuration language of tsvector

Tags: postgresql

I have a system with few full text search configuration languages.
How can I know what is the full text search configuration language of given tsvector?
TIA

I try to find a function that show the full text search configuration language of a tsvector, but I didn't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tsvector` does not have a text search configuration stored with it. The configuration is only used to generate the `tsvector`, but not stored along with it.

If you need to persist that information, you have to use a separate column.